# get all branch names associated with a particular commit hash

Tags: git

I want to find what branches are pointing at a specific git hash. So say, i do

`git checkout 2323423`

then i do

`git name-rev HEAD`

it will return me the name of the branch, if it points to that hash

however, what if multiple branches point at that hash. How do i get all of them?

I'm not sure how it picks the one it shows (out of several), but i need all of them.

I see i can list all HEADs, using

`git show-ref --head`

and i suppose i could try to match up hashes, but this seems like it should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git branch --points-at=<hash>
```

See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---points-atltobjectgt).

Answer (score 2):

The ref-listing commands have a `--points-at` option, and `git log` has a `--decorate` option (that's turned on by default for console output, as a convenience).

```
git branch --points-at @
git for-each-ref --points-at @
git log -1 --oneline @  # (or --no-walk to show each of multiple args)
```